# Sending XML with cURL command line and getting response

Tags: xml, web-services, curl, soap

I am trying to integrate my web system with a SOAP API that has a very poor documentation. They just wrote a fee lines but didn't provide many examples of how to achieve the same results. I contacted them and they said I can use cURL to communicate with their webservice.

I have to send an XML and they will send an XML back in response. They provide this request example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:Body>
<m:F2bAcaoCobranca xmlns:m="http://www.f2b.com.br/soap/wsbillingaction.xsd">
<mensagem data="2005-04-18" numero="121233"/>
<cliente conta="9023010001230123" senha="senha123"/>
<acao_cobranca numero="153079" cancelar_cobranca="" registrar_pagamento=""
registrar_pagamento_valor="" dt_registrar_pagamento="" cancelar_multa="1"
permitir_pagamento="1" dt_permitir_pagamento="2005-05-20" reenviar_email="0"
email_tosend=""/>
<acao_agendamento numero="123" cancelar_agendamento="0"/>
</m:F2bAcaoCobranca>
</soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

I have to send requests to this URL

`https://www.f2b.com.br/WSBillingAction`

I have no further information about this API. Assuming that you are an expert with cURL, SOAP and XML (because I am not!), what are the best guesses to get a response from this server?

Comment: With cURL you must first determine what type of request does the API expect. Usually get and post.

Comment: Tested, and the server replied `ERRO cliente: conta nÃ£o encontrada. `

Comment: would say a POST. @frz3993 indeed, it's just an example code. which command did you run?

Comment: Actually I made a php script to send a post request with the xml

Answer (score 0):

Put the request into a file 'request.xml', then use

```
curl --header "content-type: text/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" --data @query.xml -k "https://www.f2b.com.br/WSBillingAction"
```

Comment: hey there, nothing happens, nothing is shown in the console

Comment: The endpoint '/WSBillingAction' seems to be valid, because the request results in an error if you use e.g. /WSFooAction. However, the service does not reveal it's WSDL.